# app.js for Growl Notifications, need controller?

Tags: angularjs

Ref: https://github.com/jvandemo/angular-growl-notifications

What will be the app.js file for Growl notifications ? I just need a simple notification as shown in the " Basic Example in the link below.

http://jvandemo.github.io/angular-growl-notifications/examples/index

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we need one. Here is the Plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZHW0JKumXfdFgjTjVJz?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['growlNotifications']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

});
```